# Beautiful Soup conversion of Unicode characters to HTML entities

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, beautifulsoup

This error occurs after loading the document into beautifulsoup
The document contains entities like `&ldquo;` which gets converted to `ΓÇ£`
I want to output the html entities `&ldquo;`

Comment: dou want special character or code of special character in html

Comment: the code. just as it was written in the original html

Comment: does below code woked for u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this [refernce link](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters)

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
    print(soup.prettify(formatter="html"))
```