# BeautifulSoup HTML parser modifies a tag href

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

While using `BeautifulSoup` to parse and extract all `URLs` present in an `email`,
when `<a>` tags are extracted, the `href` value has a modified value than that present in `a` tag.

Sample code:

```py
import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_code)
for link in soup.findAll("a"):
    print(link)
    url = link.get("href")
    print(url)
    if url and "http" in url:
        html_urls.append(url)
```

link

```html
<a class="email-link email-textGray email-underline" href="https://medium.com/me/email-settings/276173762aee/75e6c9e76dd0?source=email-276173762aee-1573712256115-digest.reader-------------------------785f89d2_b50d_45eb_8b5e_7392fe13f6cf&amp;type=social" style="color: #8e8e8e; text-decoration: underline;">Unsubscribe</a>
```

url [Click-Here](https://medium.com/me/email-settings/276173762aee/75e6c9e76dd0?source=email-276173762aee-1573712256115-digest.reader-------------------------785f89d2_b50d_45eb_8b5e_7392fe13f6cf&type=social)

Type: `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`

Notice the replacement of `&amp;` with `&`

Could someone please point out why so and what exactly is happening?
Traced the code in bs4 as well but couldn't find any leads.

Comment: I think beautifulSoup changes the ‘HTML Character Entity’ like ‘&amp;’ to what it actually means like ‘&’. If you don’t want this, do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23191624/beautiful-soup-conversion-of-unicode-characters-to-html-entities

Comment: i don't understand what you want to do ? you want to escape the characters ? [check](https://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml)

Comment: I want the URLs in href to remain intact. But ```link.get('href')``` returns modified values.